# using pygame, I get 'TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not class' err

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a beginner of python & pygame, and I'm trying to make some objects using class, and screening it. but I don't konw how to get rid of the error 'TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not class'..
here is the code:

````
 ddong(pygame.Rect) :
 def __init__(self):
     self.ddong = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/user/Desktop/게임 프 
 트/pygame_basic_.py/enemy.png')
     self.ddong_size = self.ddong.get_rect().size
     self.ddong_width = self.ddong_size[0]
     self.ddong_hight = self.ddong_size[1]
     self.x_pos = randint(1, screen_width - self.ddong_width)
     self.y_pos = 0
     self.rect = self.ddong.get_rect()
     self.rect.left = self.x_pos
     self.rect.top = self.y_pos```

and if I make object through this class and `blit` it like this:

 screen.blit(enemy1, (enemy1.x_pos, enemy1.y_pos))

There comes the error message. I can't find what is wrong..

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out. plz help
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enemy1` is a `ddong` object. The first argument of `blit` needs to be a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object. The `Surface` is stored in the `ddong` attribute:

<s>`screen.blit(enemy1, (enemy1.x_pos, enemy1.y_pos))`</s>

```py
screen.blit(enemy1.ddong, (enemy1.x_pos, enemy1.y_pos))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I ask you just one more?
I defined the rect object through that class, but it doesn't work in collide.
How could I get the rect info inside the class and use it outside?
It's really confusing.. I just can't get it why it isn't working.